# Tsserver can not detect the corresponding error messages

Tags: neovim

I'm using NERDTree.

When I open a TypeScript file, tsserver can detect the corresponding error messages.

However, when I switch files and return to the previous one, any code modifications aren't detected by tsserver until I use LspRestart to trigger a recheck.

What could be the reason for this?